# Does MuleSoft support .Net Core applications

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have seen that DoTNetConnector requirements as .Net FrameWork, does it support .Net Core applications

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the Mule .Net connector mentions these scenarios:

> Supported scenarios include: executing code in an existing binary
> assembly (DLL) without modification, or new development of .NET code
> that extends the capability of your integration application. ...
>
> ...
>
> The connector supports one operation, the Execute operation, which
> allows users to select a class and a method to execute, and to pass
> the corresponding arguments for that method.

I understand that the answer is no.